# How to get the value of listView outside the setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview

How to get the value of listView outside the setOnItemClickListener?

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
{

@Override

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
              String item=listView.getSelectedItem().toString();

       }
  });
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you want to achieve?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare a string outside the listener

```
String text = null;
```

Then within the onClickListener do

```
text = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
```

Then you can call text where ever you want it.

```
if(text != null){
    Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.Length_Short).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to get this...

```
String item=listView.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

string which you want outside of listview.

1) Create a variable outside of listview and outside of your  onCreate method and call it...

```
public String item;
```

Now go back to your onItemClick and remove 'String' so it now looks like this.

```
item=listView.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Now you can call 'item' string all across your application. Go here to learn about access modifiers. http://android4beginners.com/2013/06/lesson-0-12-java-basics-more-about-methods-variables-access-modifiers-public-or-private-getters-and-setters/

Answer (score 0):

Declare the string item as a global variable before the onCreate meathod.

```
public static String item;
```

Like shown in the picture.

[image]